# Converting an integrand into a polylog?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, logarithms, polylogarithm

Compute the integral $$\int_0^1 dx\,dy\, \frac{\ln(1+y(1-x))}{1-xy}$$

I was just wondering if there is a way to convert the integrand  into a polylog? This comes from a tutorial following a lecture on polylogarithms and co-product expansions so I am thinking this is the desired method of solution. Also, what are the limits of $x$ and $y$ here? I have never seen a double integral expressed like that. Thanks!

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ does'nt mean anything. Probably this is meant to be $$\iint_{(0,1)^2}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy.$$

Comment: Ok this is what I thought, many thanks.  Any comments regarding the integral?

Comment: It is a Beuker-type integral. It can be used to prove the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path outlined below is the following: we exploit the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\log(1+z)$ in order to write the double integral as a double integral of a double series of monomials. Then, exploiting the Beta function, we integrate each monomial over the unit square, converting the last expression in a double series over $j$ and $k$. We take $n=k+j$ as a new summation parameter, computing $\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j j!(n-j)!$ in order to remove a summation sign. After that, we are left with a familiar series, related to $\zeta(3)$.

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{\log(1+y(1-x))}{1-xy}\,dx\,dy &=& \iint_{(0,1)}\sum_{k\geq 0}x^k y^k \log(1+y(1-x))\,dx\,dy\\&=&\iint_{(0,1)^2}\sum_{k,j\geq 0}(-1)^j \frac{x^k y^k y^{j+1} (1-x)^{j+1}}{j+1}\\&=&\sum_{k,j\geq 0}(-1)^j\frac{k!j!}{(k+j+2)\cdot(k+j+2)!}\\&=&\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1+(-1)^n)\cdot(n+1)!}{(n+2)^2(n+2)!}\\&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{2}{(2m+2)^3}=\color{red}{\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Ah nice, would you know if there is a method utilising polylogs at all? +1

Comment: @CAF: $\zeta(3)$ is just $\text{Li}_3(1)$, so we are using polylogarithms even here. Anyway, if we use a (highly non-trivial) change of variables and integration by parts we may convert the original integral into $$\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\text{Li}_2(z)\frac{dz}{z}.$$ Nowadays, this is a standard technique. See, for instance, https://eudml.org/doc/74995

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + y\bracks{1 - x}} \over 1 - xy}
\,\dd x\,\dd y =
-\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{1/\pars{1 + y}}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over yx\pars{1 - yx}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over y}\int_{1/\pars{1 + y}}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x}
\,\dd x\,\dd y -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over y}\int_{y/\pars{1 + y}}^{y}{\ln\pars{x/y} \over 1 - x}
\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + y} \over y}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] - &\
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over y}\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - {y \over 1 + y}}
\ln\pars{{y \over 1 + y}\,{1 \over y}} +
\int_{y/\pars{1 + y}}^{y}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + y} \over y}\,\dd y +
\int_{0}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y -
\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y \over 1 + y}\,{\dd y \over y} 
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{1}^{2}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over y - 1}\,\dd y +
\int_{0}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y -
\int_{0}^{1/2}{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y} \over y\pars{1 - y}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{1}^{1/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{1/y} \over 1/y - 1}\,\pars{-\,{1 \over y^{2}}}\,\dd y +
\int_{1/2}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y -
\int_{0}^{1/2}{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over y\pars{1 - y}}\,\dd y +
\int_{1/2}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{y}\,\dd y +
\ln\pars{1 \over 2}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}
\\[5mm] - &\
\int_{0}^{1/2}\ln\pars{1- y}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{y}\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y -
{1 \over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y +
\bracks{\zeta\pars{3} - \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2}} -
\ln\pars{2}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}
\\[5mm] + &\
\int_{0}^{1/2}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - y} \over y}\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 6}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + \zeta\pars{3} - \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2} -
\ln\pars{2}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2} -
{1 \over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] + &\
\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 6}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + \zeta\pars{3} - \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2} -
\ln\pars{2}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 2}\int_{1/2}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

However,
\begin{align}
\int{\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over 1 - y}\,\dd y & =
-\ln\pars{1 - y}\ln^{2}\pars{y} + \int\ln\pars{1 - y}
\,{2\ln\pars{y} \over y}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{1 - y}\ln^{2}\pars{y} - 2\int\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{y}\ln\pars{y}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{1 - y}\ln^{2}\pars{y} - 2\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y}\ln\pars{y} + 2\int\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y}{1 \over y}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{1 - y}\ln^{2}\pars{y} - 2\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{y}\ln\pars{y} + 2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{y}
\end{align}

---

\eqref{1} becomes
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + y\bracks{1 - x}} \over 1 - xy}
\,\dd x\,\dd y}} =
-\,{1 \over 6}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + \zeta\pars{3} - \mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2} -
\ln\pars{2}\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}
\\[5mm] + &\
{1 \over 2}\bracks{%
-\ln^{3}\pars{2} - 2\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2} + 2\zeta\pars{3} -
2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2}}
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{2 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + 2\zeta\pars{3} -
2\,\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2} - 2\ln\pars{2}\,\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}
\\[1cm] = &\
-\,{2 \over 3}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} + 2\zeta\pars{3} -
2\ \overbrace{\bracks{{1 \over 6}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} - {1 \over 12}\,\pi^{2}\ln\pars{2} +
{7 \over 8}\,\zeta\pars{3}}}^{\ds{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2}}}
\\[5mm] - &\ 2\ln\pars{2}\ \underbrace{\bracks{%
{1 \over 12}\,\pi^{2} - {1 \over 2}\,\ln^{2}\pars{2}}}
_{\ds{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}}} = \bbox[15px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{{1 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}}}
\end{align}

> In the above expression I used
>   [well known values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Particular_values)
>   of $\ds{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{1 \over 2}}$ and
>   $\ds{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over 2}}$.